# Amcharts: Colorize the items of a Radar Column Series

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I would like to create a radar chart with Amcharts. The value "value" should be displayed as a RadarColumnSeries. But the elements should have an individual color. I tried to set the colors by setting the configField = "config" and add the color value to the data set. But the color of all elements stays the same. Any idea?

The code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lefrank/1kft0sd3/3

or:

```
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="amcharts/core.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/charts.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var radarChart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

radarChart.data= [
{"element":"One","value": 68,"config": {"fill": "#fff000" }},
{"element":"Two","value": 58,"config": {"fill": "#fff000" }},
{"element":"Three","value": 88,"config": {"fill": "#fff000" }}
];

var categoryAxis = radarChart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "element";

var radarValueAxis = radarChart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
radarValueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fill = "#ff0000";
radarValueAxis.renderer.axisFills.template.fillOpacity = 0.05;
radarValueAxis.min = 0;
radarValueAxis.max = 100;

var radarSeries = radarChart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
radarSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
radarSeries.name = "Value";
radarSeries.dataFields.categoryX = "element";
radarSeries.dataFields.valueY = "value";
radarSeries.columns.template.configField = "config";

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it:

radarSeries1.columns.template.radarColumn.configField = 'config';